# Postifx: how can someone send e-mail without authorization with this configuration?

Tags: linux, postfix, smtp, smtp-auth

Yesterday I found that 10 thousand e-mail messages were sent through my system using this configuration:
http://pastebin.com/bThpH1s8 - main.cf
http://pastebin.com/kkxxsstP - master.cf

I temporarily blocked the whole spamer's ISP's IP range, but obviously the problem is in the Postfix configuration. 25 port is now closed, so relay tests give a negative answer.
I wonder if there anything else I could do to HAVE 25 port open and a closed relay SMTP server? Why does it allow unauthorized use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You allow relaying from 0/0 in main.cf main.cf

```
mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0 [::/0]
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems that this was my problem. Now it all works perfectly, all tests passed and hopefully no more spamming.

Answer (score 1):

Under `smtpd_client_restrictions` (and also `smtpd_relay_restrictions` and `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`) you have `permit_mynetworks` but you also have `mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0 [::/0]`.  This allows any IP address to ignore these restrictions and send mail through your mail server.

You should change `mynetworks` to only list trusted IPs.

If you intend to receive mail for your domain and store it, you should also have [`permit_auth_destination`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#permit_auth_destination) in your `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`.

Comment: `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` must contain at least one reject_* restriction, or postfix will not accept it. The default of `permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, permit` accomplishes this, i.e. you cannot simply switch to `permit_auth_destination`. The full discussion is long, so I won't put it here; consult the documentation for issues with too broad permit_* restrictions.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest *replacing* the existing `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` with just `permit_auth_destination` but rather adding it to the existing one.  Replacing it would cause Postfix to stop working.  The output of `postconf -d permit_auth_destination` doesn't contain `permit`.  Is there an implicit `permit` that's not listed?

Comment: There is both an implied default permit, and a hard rule on which type of restrictions *must* appear, as I said above.